# Apache problem reading network drive using alias in httpd.conf

Tags: windows-xp, network-share, httpd.conf, apache-2.2

I have **Windows XP professional (SP3)** running + **XAMPP with Apache 2.2.12.** Everything is properly installed and **works fine with local drives**.

The problem is that I **want to access network drive "U:/"** using **alias** defined in Apaches **http.conf** file:

```
Alias /w1/ "C:\workspace" // works
Alias /w2/ "U:\workspace" // does not work
```

Network drive U is hosted somewhere else and i cannot change any settings there.
I know that apache is running under another user and therefor is not able to find the network drive U. **What can i do to make it work as a windows service?**

I already tried to use DocumentRoot/Alias with UNC using the windows service "Log on As" with my own account.

**EDIT:** What at least works is: Running apache over console using the parameter "-c" with an additional setting apllied after the httpd.conf:

```
httpd.exe -c "alias /e U:\"
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If apache is running as system account, it can't use network resources.

If apache is running as normal user, it can use network resources, but only in UNC format `\\server\share_name`.

[Running Apache as service on Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#winsvc)

Try to use an alias as DocumentRoot:

Alias /home/htdocs //FILESERVER/share/home/htdocs

And then you can use:

DocumentRoot /home/htdocs

Comment: already tried to run the apache service under my own account - but it did not work without UNC. I am still trying to figure out how i get the UNC.

Comment: how would the line in httpd.conf look like when using UNC for a local directory?

Comment: I added a link in my response, read it!

Comment: i already tried to run the apache service using "Log on as" my own user account. But the network ressource is still not accessible (DocumentRoot must be a directory).

Comment: I found this link (http://adam-carter.com/posts/158) and seems it is possible. Sorry for question, but the account you are using...can access the share?

Comment: yes the account i am using can access the share

Comment: Try with alias...I just edited my answer. Ops...you just tried this solution! I have no more ideas.

Comment: thx for your help,but it no does not work: "DocumentRoot must be a directory", i somehow got the feeling that the service functionality is not use the permissions of my account while using "Log on"