# Apache service has no access to network drive

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, network-share, service, xampp

Im trying to get a xampp installation running. In my httpd.conf i use the following DocumentRoot setting:

DocumentRoot //DiskStation/Work/htdocs

If i now start the apache service i'll get the following error:

> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>   DocumentRoot must be a directory     .

For several hours i thought i've used the wrong DocumentRoot setting in the Apache config. Until i started the apace process manually. The apache was up and running and i could access my resources via localhost.

I also found a lot of hints to give the Apache service specific user permissions:
http://adam-carter.com/posts/158
[Apache problem reading network drive using alias in httpd.conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/160649/apache-problem-reading-network-drive-using-alias-in-httpd-conf)

But still I'm not able to start the Apache as a service, even if i use my own account details.

Anybody got an idea what could cause the problem that the service can not access the network drive though I use my own windows user account credentials for the startup.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer to the question, do not edit the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours figuring out what might work, the following bit different solution worked for me:

1. Create a new Windows User with normal user rights (no admin rights)
2. Login with this user account and map your network drive you want to use
3. Logout and Login in your normal user account.
4. Now edit the apache service to run under the created user privileges (described here: http://adam-carter.com/posts/158) and everything should running.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before, and [this link](http://adam-carter.com/posts/158) can provide you some answers.

That's the solution:

1. Change your DocumentRoot to the network share (drive remapping doesn’t seem to work).  Example: `DocumentRoot "//path/to/share"`
2. Make sure to update the DocumentRoot path in your  config
3. Edit the Apache service:

   - On the "Log On" tab, click the "Browse" button next to the "This account" radio button.
   - Type in an account name that has access privileges to the network share and click "OK"
   - Enter the correct password for the user

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i already tried that. What didn't work for me was using my own user (admin) account to start the service. It worked when I created a standart user and used this user to start the service. Took me several hours to figure out, so maybe I can safe some people some time mentioning that.